How to handle consecutive .into() calls?
I have an external type Foo, and use both the .into() and .parse() methods for it in my code:
let foo: Foo = some_array.into();
let foo_again: Foo = "some string".parse()?;

Now, I want to replace it with a wrapper type that overrides a trait impl for Foo, but this breaks the code above:
struct Wrapper(pub Foo);

// These now both error, because `Wrapper` doesn't implement `From` and `FromStr`
let foo: Wrapper = some_array.into();
let foo_again: Wrapper = "some string".parse()?;

// These error because they need additional type annotation for the intermediate value
let foo: Wrapper = some_array.into().into();
let foo_again: Wrapper = "some string".parse()?.into();


I can manually implement From and FromStr that just call Foo::From and Foo::FromStr, but that seems redundant. So I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to handle this (e.g. a trait like Borrow or a macro).

How about let foo[_again] = Wrapper(expression);? Rust will know that the inside of Wrapper has to be a Foo, which will get type inference working again on the expression.

@BallpointBen That would work! Unfortunately in my actual code, the type names are longer and the values are not used as cleanly as in this toy example. So making that change everywhere would lead to even messier code than just implementing the traits manually for the wrapper.

Well you'll have to specify the name of the type somewhere; .into().into() can never work.

Implementing From and FromStr for Wrapper seems like the most idiomatic solution to me.  If you object to the boilerplate then perhaps you can find some library (for example derive_more) that provides a convenient #[derive(From, FromStr)] for such cases (or else you could write one).

I'm not sure if this is a direct answer, but if you're asking how to annotate the into call, you can't because the generics are on the trait and not the method. The way I usually handle this is to directly invoke from. This happens most often to me with numeric types where multiple destination types would work. For example, I'll do u32::from(x) instead of x.into().
